# Create a folder/file on onedrive with app-only authorization flow (without signing in), MSGRAPH

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I am trying to create a folder or file on OneDrive with app-only authorization flow, request and response details are as below,

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children  
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
AUTHORIZATION: Bearer <AccesToken>
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 39

Request Body
{"name": "Hello.docx", "file": {} }

Response:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
    "innerError": 
      {
      "request-id": "xxxxx-b23d-482c-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2016-03-11T12:49:06"
      }
  }
}
```

If it's something to do with permissions, can you please let me know which application permission to be set so this could work? Does it even work in App-Only authorization flow?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Prasad, Can you also share your app configuration (what permissions it has to the Microsoft Graph), as well as some code which shows your authentication process? Are you an admin of the tenant you are trying to access? Did an admin of the tenant you are trying to access consent to your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately access using app-only tokens is not yet supported by the OneDrive entities. This is definitely something on our radar that we hope to add soon, so please stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I used the delegated authorization flow and it worked.